# How to properly display value in edit form while using bootstrap3_autocomplete_input and association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, associations, simple-form

I am trying to use auto-complete/type-ahead feature provided by following Rails gem  https://github.com/maxivak/bootstrap3_autocomplete_input , together with https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Everything works fine in case I choose "new" action for new record in form. I am able to choose value in input field by auto-complete feature. Problem is in case i choose "edit" action to edit already existing record. In that case field does not show correct value (pre-filled by form), but it shows something like: `#<Airport:0x007f98b478b7a8>`

Even in "show" action, I can see correct value displayed.

I tried to change  f.input with f.association as I had it before I started implementing auto-complete, but this did not helped.

Records in Cargo model have correct airports_id reference stored, I checked that manually in rails console.

Question is how can I get correct Airport value pre-filled by form in case I choose "edit" action, instead some kind of reference, I got.

Rails 4.1.7

**My code is:**

**Cargo model:**

```
class Cargo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :airport
...
```

**Cargo view:**

```
...
<%= f.input :airport, :as => :autocomplete, :source_query => autocomplete_airport_city_airports_url %>
...
```

**Airport model:**

```
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cargos, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :iata_code, :name, :city
  validates :iata_code, :name, :city, presence: true
  validates :iata_code, :uniqueness => { :scope => :name }
  validates :iata_code, length: { is: 3 }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z\d\s]*\z/ }
  validates :name, :city, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 128 }

  def full_airport_name
    "#{city} / #{iata_code}"
  end
end
```

**Airports controller**

```
class AirportsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :airport, :city, { :display_value => 'full_airport_name', :full_model=>true }
...
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :airports do
  get :autocomplete_airport_city, :on => :collection
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the problem. First of all I refactored `Airports model`, removed all columns but `name`, and reseed name column with data concatenated from separate strings `IATA code / City`. After this, there is need to specify in model, what to show as value. Simply this solved this issue:

```
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cargos, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

This is described, I didnot understand it on first sight previously, in original documentation here https://github.com/maxivak/bootstrap3_autocomplete_input section Model.

Answer (score 0):

User `f.association` and because rails will automatically look for `:name`and you do not have that, you'll have to define it like so:

`f.association :airport, label_method: :full_airport_name, value_method: :id........etc`

Comment: OK thanx, this is actually what I had before this generates dropdownlist with all options,

`f.association :airport, :label_method => :full_airport_name, :value_method => :id , :order => :iata_code, :prompt => :translate`

but my goal was to implement autocomplete/typeahed https://github.com/maxivak/bootstrap3_autocomplete_input  instead of  dropdown box.

Comment: Do you still want an autocomplete input box on edit?

Comment: I would need autocomplete input box, which lookup to another table to autocomplete query. These values should not be editable just selectable. I am not sure if I am explaining that correctly, sorry about my english.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. The reason rails gives you `#<Airport:0x007f98b478b7a8>` is because your `Airport` doesn't have a `:name` attribute. This is what rails uses to display. On an association, we use `input_label` to customize this. On an `textbox`....hmm, have you tried using the `value` property? `input_html: {value: : full_airport_name}`? Sorry, I'm ballparking it now